# Use `\ifblank` as a test for `\ifstrequal`

Tags: macros, etoolbox

To carry out checks on some parameters passed to an environment, I would need to:

1. check if the parameter is blank or not;
2. pass a default value or the one supplied;
3. compare the final value with a string and then decide what to do.

Without going into the details of the context, I think the situation can be boiled down to this MWE:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#1}{pluto}
        {a}
        {b}%
}

\newcommand{\foofoo}[1][]{\ifblank{#1}{pluto}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\foo{\foofoo}

\foo{\foofoo[]}

\foo{\foofoo[ ]}

\foo{\foofoo[pluto]}

\foo{\foofoo[pippo]}

\end{document}
```

Running those commands I would expect to get "a" in all but the last case. Instead, "b" is always printed.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get the result I want?

**EDIT:**

New MWE to try to better understand the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

\newcounter{mysecondcounter}
\setcounter{mysecondcounter}{1}

\newcommand{\counterFormat}[1]{%
    \thesubsection.\arabic{#1}
}

\newcommand{\myTitle}[3]{%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}{hidecounter}
        {#2}
        {#2 \counterFormat{#3}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ O{} O{} O{} }{
    \myTitle
        {\ifblank{#1}{hidecounter}{#1}}
        {\ifblank{#2}{Example}{#2}}
        {\ifblank{#3}{mycounter}{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\foo

\foo[showcounter][][ ]

\foo[showcounter][][mysecondcounter]

\foo[][Demo]

\foo[showcounter][Demo][ ]

\end{document}
```

My question is, does it make sense to handle arguments this way? Or is there a more correct and clean solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Your `\foofoo` command is not expandable; but that's the least of your problems: in any case its first level expansion triggered by the `\expandafter` chain always produces a non blank token list.

Answer (score 5):

No matter of how many expansion steps you apply to `\foofoo`, it will ***never*** produce a blank token list (empty or only consisting of spaces).

Why? Because you define it with an optional argument. But even if you define it with a mandatory argument, the situation changes little and one expansion step is not sufficient. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#1}{pluto}
        {a}
        {b}%
}

\newcommand{\foofoo}[1]{\ifblank{#1}{pluto}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\foo{\foofoo{}}

\foo{\foofoo{ }}

\foo{\foofoo{pluto}}

\foo{\foofoo{pippo}}

\end{document}
```

produces four b's. You want to *fully* expand `#1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}{pluto}
        {a}
        {b}%
}

\newcommand{\foofoo}[1]{\ifblank{#1}{pluto}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\foo{\foofoo{}}

\foo{\foofoo{ }}

\foo{\foofoo{pluto}}

\foo{\foofoo{pippo}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Greg,
thanks for the reply, your solution works perfectly.

However, since I don't quite understand how expansion works or what it means to be expandable or not, I added a MWE more similar to my doc's code to the question.